# axios cannot access message of an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, axios

I have a function which  use axios get method and on the promised returned I have added error handling to handle a situation when service I am trying to connect to has been disabled.

```
axios.get('/someurl')
    .then(() => {
        // this does not matter
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        logger.error(TAG, 'postCreateVm', err);
        return reply(Boom.forbidden(err.message));
    });
```

When I use curl I can see the message, status of response is 403:

```
# curl -X GET localhost:3000/someurl
{
    "message": "abort"
}
```

The problem is that when I try to access 'message' property i get nothing, but I know it's there! (I have tried to use err.response.data as well with no success also)

According to the documentation I should be able to access it: [axios handling errors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#handling-errors)

What is the proper way to access this message?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've looked at his code, and it appears the correct response is in the error, but in axios, settle.js masks it with a generic response. You can see the server response by logging the error object in your catch block as stringified JSON:

```
console.log('caught:::', JSON.stringify(response, null, 2))
```

So in my case, I fixed it by accessing the returned error as:

```
error.response.data.message
```

Comment: It also depends on the server side. I have my server side in Python and Flask, and it turned out the error message was not sent (I have a try-catch and in the catch block I re-raise the same exception). After registering an error handler like explained here http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/apierrors/ the error message was accessible like in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

My catch function received the response property instead of error object. So, to access message I had use:

```
err.data.message
```